# How to display columns by steps (after click) in beamer

Tags: beamer, two-column

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{frame-1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item term 1
      \item \alt<2->{\xout{term 2}}{term 2}
      \item term 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frame-2}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
%contents
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
%contents
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
%contents
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to display column 1 & 2 together then column3 after click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward given that the column admits the overlay specifier directly:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{frame-1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item term 1
      \item \alt<2->{\xout{term 2}}{term 2}
      \item term 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frame-2}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}<1->{0.2\textwidth}
contents 1
\end{column}
\begin{column}<1->{0.4\textwidth}
contents 2
\end{column}
\begin{column}<2->{0.4\textwidth}
contents 3
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(I added a bit of content to the columns, otherwise is difficult to see anything )